# LibGDX обработка нажатий

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Некорректная работа ***InputProcessor*** на андроиде версии выше 5.1 (судя по проведенным тестам)

При удержании на ***left-ui-button/right-ui-button*** должен вызываться метод `onDragged()`, а вызывается он только если двигать палец по кнопке (изменять координаты нажатия)

Код:

```
public boolean touchDown(int xx, int yy, int point, int ignore){
    Vector2 p=getPoint(point);
    if(story!=null && story.len()>0){
        if(!story.next()){
            if(level.hasTag("start-dialog")){
                level.removeTag("start-dialog");
                again();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    if(getUI().isTouched("jump-ui-button",p)){
        jump();
        return false;
    }else if(getUI().isTouched("reset-ui-button",p)){
        again();
        return false;
    }else if(getUI().isTouched("left-ui-button",p)){
        return false;
    }else if(getUI().isTouched("right-ui-button",p)){
        return false;
    }else if(getUI().isTouched("ash-ui-button",p)){
        sm.pop();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int point, int ignore){
    return false;
}

public boolean touchDragged(int x, int y, int point){
    if(story!=null && story.len()>0){
        return true;
    }
    Vector2 p=getPoint(point);
    if(getUI().isTouched("left-ui-button",p)){
        moveLeft();
    }
    if(getUI().isTouched("right-ui-button",p)){
        moveRight();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден.
Был сделан костыль в виде прослушки нажатий при обновлении игры для обработки их как в методе `touchDragged()`